# VB 2D Array possibly not returning correct value/Need help counting number of booleans in a 2d array

Tags: vb.net, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to write Conways game of life in visual basic but there seems to be a problem with the code that counts the number of living surrounding cells. The code is shown below:

```
Module Module1

Dim ScreenHeight As Integer = 30
Dim ScreenWidth As Integer = 30
Dim Field(ScreenWidth - 1, ScreenHeight - 1) As Boolean
Dim FieldBuffer(ScreenWidth - 1, ScreenHeight - 1) As Boolean

Sub Main()
    Console.SetWindowSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)
    Field(10, 9) = True
    Field(10, 10) = True
    Field(10, 11) = True


    While True

        Dim x = 0
        While (x < ScreenWidth)
            Dim y = 0
            While (y < ScreenHeight)
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y)

                If ((x <> 0 And x <> ScreenWidth - 1) And (y <> 0 And y <> ScreenWidth - 1)) Then

                    Dim count = Field(x + 1, y) + Field(x - 1, y) + Field(x, y + 1) + Field(x, y - 1) _
                        + Field(x + 1, y + 1) + Field(x - 1, y - 1) + Field(x - 1, y + 1) + Field(x + 1, y - 1)

                    count = count * -1
                    If (Field(x, y) = True) Then

                        If (count < 2) Then
                            FieldBuffer(x, y) = False
                        End If
                        If (count > 3) Then
                            FieldBuffer(x, y) = False
                        End If
                        If (count = 3 Or count = 2) Then
                            FieldBuffer(x, y) = True
                        End If


                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
                    Else

                        If (count = 3) Then
                            FieldBuffer(x, y) = True
                        End If

                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
                    End If

                    Console.Write(count)
                Else
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                    Console.Write("X")
                End If


                y += 1
            End While
            x += 1
        End While

        Console.ReadKey()
        Field = FieldBuffer
    End While



End Sub

End Module
```

The code that gets the values of the surrounding cells is:

```
Dim count = Field(x + 1, y) + Field(x - 1, y) + Field(x, y + 1) + Field(x, y - 1) _
+ Field(x + 1, y + 1) + Field(x - 1, y - 1) + Field(x - 1, y + 1) + Field(x + 1, y - 1)
count = count * -1
```

For the first iteration of the program, it returns the right values for the cell structure in the Field array.
But on the second iteration, after applying the rules, it doesn't return the correct values, which should be:
12321
11211
12321

The rules are being applied to the array correctly because after the first iteration the structure that is being displayed is correct. This bug has also appeared when having an 'If(Field(x,y) = true) then Count+=1' for every position surrounding the cell.

Any help would be appreciated as this bug has been driving me crazy for about 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are wrong.

```
' Any live cell with two or three neighbours lives
' Any dead cell with exactly three live
If count = 3 Then ' If (count = 3 Or count = 2) Then
    FieldBuffer(x, y) = True
End If
```

You are also copying the reference. This mean, on the second pass, Field and FieldBuffer are the same.

```
Field = FieldBuffer
```

You need to copy each item. Use a loop, something like [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx) or [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390987/net-writing-one-2d-array-onto-another).